# Require whole or part of lodash library

Tags: gulp, browserify, lodash

I am using gulp and browserify to generate 2 files - `vendor.js` with all the libraries (jquery, lodash, etc.) and `main.js` with my code only where I am requiring libraries from vendor.js similar to this [browserify recipe](https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes/blob/master/browserify-separating-app-and-vendor-bundles/gulpfile.js).

I am wondering if there is any benefit in requiring part of lodash library against whole lodash library in this case?

For example,
`var _ = require('lodash/object')` vs `var _ = require('lodash')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case requiring `lodash` selectively caused `main.js` to include selected part of lodash as well. This caused `lodash` to be present in both `vendor.js` and `main.js`.
So the correct answer in my case (if using `vendor.js` for libraries and `main.js` for own code) is to require `lodash` in this way - `var _ = require('lodash')` only.

Answer (score 0):

Your vendor bundle ought to be smaller (maybe a lot) if you require `lodash` modules selectively vs. the whole thing. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. Same size of `vendor.js` in both cases in my project.

Comment: So when you create the vendor bundle you're doing something like this, right?: `browserify().require('lodash/object', {expose: 'lodash/object'})`.

Comment: Yes, I am doing:   `_.forEach(npmPackages, (id) => b.require(nodeResolve.sync(id), { expose: id }));` where `npmPackages` are all libraries under `dependencies` in `package.json`. So the whole `lodash` library is present in `vendor.js`. Does it mean that there is no difference in my case if  I require `lodash` modules selectively vs. the whole thing?

Comment: I think you should post `dependencies` from your `package.json` in your question.